# Using Azure Data Factory and OData connector to get data from Google-Facebook

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'd like to know if it is possible to get data from Google (e.g. Google Analytics) and Facebook by using Azure Data Factory v1 and the supported OData connector.
Any suggests to me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this would depend on: could you get the odata service url and authentication?